Moving Laravel project from localhost to remote
I have already read a lot on the topic without having solved the problem...
I'd like to deploy an old, simple Laravel 7.x project (working perfectly locally) on a remote server (shared at 'aruba.it') for testing purposes, maintaining the original structure of a usual Laravel installation.
I uploaded everything to 'https://www.mydomain.it/laravel/laravel-project', when asking for that I obtain '403 Forbidden'.
When asking for 'www.mydomain.it/laravel/laravel-project/.env' I get the file view, I think you already know this too...
When asking for 'www.mydomain.it/laravel/laravel-project/public' I get 'www.mydomain.it/posts' with '404 Not Found' (in '/routes/web.php' I have 'Route::redirect('/', '/posts');'; and in any case I wouldn't want to add 'public' on the URL.
As research suggests I placed '.htaccess' in '.../laravel-project' with this code:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] </IfModule>,
at least I get the 'Not Found' Laravel's view...
Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the '.env' file too? For example, what exactly should I write under 'APP_URL'?
Thanks in advance.

"... I get the file view" Ouch! Not sure why/how we should know that. Laravel should be installed as the only project for a (sub)domain. The domain's webserver/DocumentRoot should point to the public/ folder

'I get the file view, I think you already know this too...': I meant 'this shouldn't happen'...
